# Need help interpreting "silver" hallmark - 1706?

Tags: 18th-century, silver, silver-hallmark

I'm looking for some assistance in interpreting the silver hallmark in the image below. EPNS tells us it's not real silver, could 1706 really be the true date with that in mind? What does the shell-like stamp tell us? Origin? Found in Sweden, while this may not necessarily be its origin.

Thank you very much,
Fredrik

[image]

Comment: The shell might be [Ellis-Barker Silver Co.](http://www.925-1000.com/silverplate_E.html)

Comment: I'd would have thought that 1706 was too early for electro-plating - possibly a batch number?

Comment: Definitely not a date. The font is modern.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with (non-trivial) history.

Comment: I agree with @TylerDurden. If you rewrite your question to prove it is historical subject, I will cancel my closing vote.

Answer (score 3):

It looks you have an Electro Plated Nickel Silver.
The technology is not old enough to origin from 18th century.

[From a site](http://www.silvercollection.it/DICTIONARYEPNS.html) where you can find identical font type:

> Modern electroplating was invented by Italian chemist Luigi V. Brugnatelli in 1805.

And the picture which is similar enough:

[image]

So the number as Steve Bird suspected correcty it should be a batch number. Most probably your item and this one made in very different series, but the material is the same. It doesn't contain silver, it's content typically are: 60% copper, 20% nickel and 20% zinc. This formula also known as (in)famous [german silver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel_silver), beginner silver investors sometimes fall into the trap mixing up it with real silver. It's density is significantly less than real silver. It is 8.3 gr/cm3 instead of 10.5 gr/cm3.